# Navigate on application resume Event

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

On resume event I want to redirect the application to a certain page if a variable is present.

Everything is working fine but the router Navigation.

I got the "Cannot read property navigate of undefined"

I included the RouterExtensions in the constructor.

Below the code I'm using:

```
eventInitialization(): void {
    applicationOn(resumeEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {

        if (args[0].android) {
            var act = args[0].android;
            var intent = act.getIntent();
            var extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras) {
                var not_id = extras.get('not_id');
                if (not_id){


                    this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/page",not_id]);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```